# not able to post request from my react native app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-hooks

i have created backend server and its working correctly . i did verify it using postman
so i have this as my backend url http://localhost:5000
now i want to store a phone number inside my db.
but it seems that i am not able to establish connection with my backend server

this is the error i am facing
[image]

updated error

[image]

[image]

[image]

i am using axios

```
import axios from 'axios';


const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
});

export default instance;
```

and this is how i am trying to post my data
error is caused when i am trying to connect to my server see from this line
const resp = await lifeApi.post('/signup', { data });

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import lifeApi from '../../api/life';

//const User = require('../../../New folder/aol-backend/src/models/User');

const VerifyOTP = ({ route: { params: { phoneNumber } }, navigation }) => {
    // If null, no SMS has been sent
    //const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(true);
    const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
    //const [otpArray, setOtpArray] = useState(['', '', '', '']);
    const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);
    //const User = require('../../../../folder/src/models/User');
    useEffect(() => {
        signInWithPhoneNumber();
    }, []);

    async function signInWithPhoneNumber() {
        try {
            const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            setConfirm(confirmation);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    }
//==========================this is where i am trying to post request ==================================================
    async function confirmCode() {
        try {
            const code = otp;
            const response = await confirm.confirm(code);

            //================
            const data = { phone: response.user._user.phoneNumber };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            try {
                const resp = await lifeApi.post('/signup', { data });
                console.log(resp);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            //================
            console.log(response.user._user.phoneNumber);
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        } catch (e) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    }
//=============================================================================
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={style.display}
                value={otp}
                onChangeText={text => setOtp(text)}
                keyboardType="number-pad"
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    confirmCode();
                }}
            >
                <Text>
                    submit
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    display: {
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 2,
    }
});
export default VerifyOTP;

/**
          *  if (response) {
             await new User({
                 phone: response.user._user.phoneNumber
             }).save();
          */
```

please if you need any more information on my question , do tell
please help...

Comment: "Network error" isn't very informative. Is there anything else displayed in the console? Perhaps something about CORS?

Comment: hi Quentin , i have added all the error logs that i am getting,

Comment: You need to plug open an actual debugger and not look only at the messages exposed to JavaScript. Network errors tend to have the details heavily redacted when being passed around in Error objects that JS can read because they often contain privileged information about third party websites which should not be exposed to the JS running on the first party website.

Answer (score 0):

1. Local machine (Laptop/Desktop) in which server application is running and Mobile device should be connected to same network.

   - Connect your mobile device with Wi-Fi to your local network.
   - Connect your Laptop also same network. (Server is running in laptop)
2. Check IP of laptop by running a command in terminal (ifconfig/ipconfig)
3. Set above IP address in Mobile application Which app you want to test it.

   ```
    const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://192.168.0.29:5000'}); //IP:Port number
   ```